# Prove that $E(X\ln X)\le E X E\ln X$

Tags: probability, inequality

I want to prove it using Jensen inequality, so I need to prove that $g(x)=x\ln x$ is a convex function, which means 
$$g\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\le \frac{1}{2}\left(g(a)+g(b)\right).$$
How can I prove it?

Comment: Hi and welcome!  Does $E(\ldots)$ denote the expected value? What does $EXE$ mean?  Maybe putting brackets help.

Comment: Tip: a differentiable function is convex iff its second derivative is nonnegative.

Comment: I think you need a space in there.

Comment: The statement "$E(X\log X)\le E(X)E(\log X)$" is not true.

As a counterexample, let $X$ be a discrete variable with equal chances of being $1$ or $e$ whose logarithms are $0$ and $1$ respectively.  Then $X\log X$ has equal chances of being $0$ or $e,$ with expectation $e/2.$  But $E(X)=(1+e)/2$ and $E(\log X) = 1/2,$ entailing

$$E(X\log X) = e/2 \approx 1.36 \gt 0.93 \approx \left(\frac{1+e}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = E(X)E(\log X).$$
 In light of this, could you please clarify what you're trying to show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remark: the sign seems to be flipped.

Here is how we can prove

> if $X> 0$, then $$E(X \ln X) \ge E(X) E(\ln X)$$

We can apply Jensen's inequality twice.

$x\ln x$ is convex, hence we have,$$E[X] \ln (E[X]) \le E(X\ln X)$$

$\ln x$ is concave, hence we have

$$\ln (E(X)) \ge E(\ln X).$$

Combining the two inequalities, $$E(X \ln X) \ge E[X] \ln(E(X)) \ge E[X]E(\ln X)$$

To check that $x\ln x$ is convex, check the second derivative is positive. To check that $\ln x$ is concave, check that the second derivative is negative.

Comment: Wikipedia lists Jensen's inequality as $\phi( E[X] ) \le E[ \phi(X) ] $ for a convex function $\phi$. For $\phi(x) = x \ln{x}$ that expands to $E[X] \ln{E[X]} \le E[ X \ln{X} ] $. That seems opposite in sign from what you and the original question have. Are you sure a typo in the question didn't lead to a sign error in the answer?

Comment: Given the ambiguity in the question's title, would you please state explicitly what you think have proven?